# Aurelia model with no view returns error on logout

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, aurelia

I am new in the Aurelia community and it was given to me a task to make an entire upgrade of my current platform. (more info at the bottom).

Current problem:
Every time i redirect to the logout.js model a message is prompt

> ERROR [app-router] TypeError: "this.view is null"

Questions:
How does a custom component "if-permission" can influence on non-view model?

Conlusions:
 - I started to believe that any of the big files bellow are influencing the error at all! After commenting most of the code the error what still showing!
 - Removed the noView() logic and added an empty logout.html! Guess what? Works like a charm! The logout will redirect to the login page.

This is my RouteConfig.js

```
    {
      route: 'logout',
      viewPorts: {
        main: {
          moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('pages/logout/logout')
        }
      },
      nav: false,
      sidebar: false,
      auth: false,
      title: 'Logout',
      name: 'logout',
    }
```

This is my logout.js

```
import { noView } from 'aurelia-framework';
import authService from 'services/authService';
import uiService from 'services/uiService';

@noView()
export class LogoutPage {
  activate() {
    //THE ERROR PROMPTS EVEN WITH THE ABOVE LINES COMMENTED
    uiService.impersonate(null, false);
    authService.logout();
  }
}
```

After searching a while i noticed that "this.view" is declared on this 2 files:

if-permission.js

```
import { inject, customAttribute, templateController, BoundViewFactory, ViewSlot } from 'aurelia-framework';
import userService from 'services/api/userService';

@customAttribute('if-permission')
@inject(BoundViewFactory, ViewSlot)
@templateController
export class IfPermission {

  constructor(viewFactory, viewSlot) {

    this.viewFactory = viewFactory;
    this.viewSlot = viewSlot;
    this.showing = false;
    this.view = null;
    this.bindingContext = null;
    this.overrideContext = null;
  }

  /**
  * Binds the if to the binding context and override context
  * @param bindingContext The binding context
  * @param overrideContext An override context for binding.
  */
  bind(bindingContext, overrideContext) {
    // Store parent bindingContext, so we can pass it down
    this.bindingContext = bindingContext;
    this.overrideContext = overrideContext;
    this.valueChanged(this.value);
  }

  valueChanged(newValue) {
    if (this.__queuedChanges) {
      this.__queuedChanges.push(newValue);
      return;
    }

    let maybePromise = this._runValueChanged(newValue);
    if (maybePromise instanceof Promise) {
      let queuedChanges = this.__queuedChanges = [];

      let runQueuedChanges = () => {
        if (!queuedChanges.length) {
          this.__queuedChanges = undefined;
          return;
        }

        let nextPromise = this._runValueChanged(queuedChanges.shift()) || Promise.resolve();
        nextPromise.then(runQueuedChanges);
      };

      maybePromise.then(runQueuedChanges);
    }
  }

  _runValueChanged(newValue) {
    newValue = userService.hasPermission(newValue);
    if (!newValue) {
      let viewOrPromise;
      if (this.view !== null && this.showing) {
        viewOrPromise = this.viewSlot.remove(this.view);
        if (viewOrPromise instanceof Promise) {
          viewOrPromise.then(() => this.view.unbind());
        } else {
          this.view.unbind();
        }
      }
      this.showing = false;
      return viewOrPromise;
    }

    if (this.view === null) {
      this.view = this.viewFactory.create();
    }

    if (!this.view.isBound) {
      this.view.bind(this.bindingContext, this.overrideContext);
    }

    if (!this.showing) {
      this.showing = true;
      return this.viewSlot.add(this.view);
    }
  }

  /**
  * Unbinds the if
  */
  unbind() {
    if (this.view === null) {
      return;
    }

    this.view.unbind();

    if (!this.viewFactory.isCaching) {
      return;
    }

    if (this.showing) {
      this.showing = false;
      this.viewSlot.remove(this.view, true, true);
    }
    this.view.returnToCache();
    this.view = null;
  }
}
```

if-user-role.js

```
import { inject, customAttribute, templateController, BoundViewFactory, ViewSlot } from 'aurelia-framework';
import userService from 'services/api/userService';

@customAttribute('if-user-role')
@inject(BoundViewFactory, ViewSlot)
@templateController
export class IfUserRole {

  constructor(viewFactory, viewSlot) {
    this.viewFactory = viewFactory;
    this.viewSlot = viewSlot;
    this.showing = false;
    this.view = null;
    this.bindingContext = null;
    this.overrideContext = null;
  }

  /**
  * Binds the if to the binding context and override context
  * @param bindingContext The binding context
  * @param overrideContext An override context for binding.
  */
  bind(bindingContext, overrideContext) {
    // Store parent bindingContext, so we can pass it down
    this.bindingContext = bindingContext;
    this.overrideContext = overrideContext;
    this.valueChanged(this.value);
  }

  valueChanged(newValue) {
    if (this.__queuedChanges) {
      this.__queuedChanges.push(newValue);
      return;
    }

    let maybePromise = this._runValueChanged(newValue);
    if (maybePromise instanceof Promise) {
      let queuedChanges = this.__queuedChanges = [];

      let runQueuedChanges = () => {
        if (!queuedChanges.length) {
          this.__queuedChanges = undefined;
          return;
        }

        let nextPromise = this._runValueChanged(queuedChanges.shift()) || Promise.resolve();
        nextPromise.then(runQueuedChanges);
      };

      maybePromise.then(runQueuedChanges);
    }
  }

  _runValueChanged(newValue) {
    newValue = userService.hasRole(newValue);

    if (!newValue) {
      let viewOrPromise;
      if (this.view !== null && this.showing) {
        viewOrPromise = this.viewSlot.remove(this.view);
        if (viewOrPromise instanceof Promise) {
          viewOrPromise.then(() => this.view.unbind());
        } else {
          this.view.unbind();
        }
      }

      this.showing = false;
      return viewOrPromise;
    }

    if (this.view === null) {
      this.view = this.viewFactory.create();
    }

    if (!this.view.isBound) {
      this.view.bind(this.bindingContext, this.overrideContext);
    }

    if (!this.showing) {
      this.showing = true;
      return this.viewSlot.add(this.view);
    }
  }

  /**
  * Unbinds the if
  */
  unbind() {
    if (this.view === null) {
      return;
    }

    this.view.unbind();
    if (!this.viewFactory.isCaching) {
      return;
    }

    if (this.showing) {
      this.showing = false;
      this.viewSlot.remove(this.view, true, true);
    }
    this.view.returnToCache();
    this.view = null;
  }
}
```

With this update i have integrated Aurelia-cli, updated aurelia-webpack and all the dependencies. Which made me switch some code like:

- Add PLATFORM.moduleName() to all my platform
- Add Require to all modules that were only getting components via < compose >

Comment: Which line in the code blocks above is throwing the error? It's quite hard to guess what's going on without knowing that. And just curious, are you aware of why it's done this way, the code are from old `If` implementation from previous versions.

Comment: The error is showing on if-permission.js (just guessing, due to the insisting of debugging via console.log ), Aurelia-console-logging is not helping that much. but i can try to copy an paste all the error statement.

Comment: No, i feel that i am not aware of why it is done this way because i am new on Aurelia and just developing on a pre-built platform.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I have edited the thread! Go take a look to my conclusions :)

Comment: Nice you to see sorted it out.

Comment: Maybe you should file an issue on that at github :)